# Semantic Issues when using STHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sthttprequest

I've imported STHTTPRequest by adding it to my project and including "STHTTPRequest.h" in my app delegate, as the instructions on the github page say to. However, I'm getting the following errors and warnings:

(Warning) Semantic Issue: `STHTTPRequest.m:805:68: Undeclared selector 'backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:'`

(Error) ARC Semantic Issue: `STHTTPRequest.m:807:63: No known class method for selector 'backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:'`

(Error) Semantic Issue: `STHTTPRequest.m:819:26: Property 'sharedContainerIdentifier' not found on object of type 'NSURLSessionConfiguration *'`

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the Base SDK of your Xcode project?

Comment: @Willeke Base SDK is 10.9 - but on the github readme it says it supports 10.7+.

Comment: `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:` and `sharedContainerIdentifier` are available in macOS 10.10+.

Comment: How would I use this library in an application targeting 10.9? It says it can be used with it.

Comment: At the end of the readme: "If you have any question, open an issue on GitHub or use the STHTTPRequest tag on StackOverflow."

Comment: I've added that tag.